# wxPython Check and Uncheck checkbox

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Is it possible to check/uncheck a check box in wxPython? For example:

```
my_checkbox = wx.CheckBox(my_sizer, wx.ID_ANY, _("My Check Box"))
self.bind(EVT_BUTTON, my_button_func, my_button)
def my_button_func(self, event):
    mycheckbox.Check()
```

Or something of the sort where I could check/uncheck the box at will.

Comment: excuse me for a syntax error with '_("My Check Box")' i am using wxglade

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"The toggle state of a wx.CheckBox can be retrived and set with the methods GetValue() and SetValue() and it's Boolean." **_ Robin Dunn: wxPython in Action _**